# Apache and Yiiframework: two applications

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, yii

I have two Yiiframework applications with this structure:

```
.framework
.site
.site2
```

But, if I try to open the site: www.mysite.com/site2 I receive 404 error of Yii(    exception.CHttpException.404) saying that he didn't find the Controller called: site2

I already added a virtualhost of site2 on my apache:

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
      ServerName www.mysite.com/site2
      ServerAlias www.mysite.com/site2
       ServerAdmin www@localhost
       DocumentRoot "/home/server/public_html/site2/"
       <Directory "/home/server/public_html/site2/">
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from All
               AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

My .htaccess that it's inside of "site folder" (I redirect to https://):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1
```

I want that, when I open the site: www.mysite.com/site2 goes to my subdirectory /site2 and not /site. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: ServerName and ServerAlias do not take folder paths only domain names, and you do not need to use the same domain name on both so you only need ServerName.

Answer (score 0):

Site 2 is not a site, but a subdirectory in the URL www.mysite.com/site2

The ServerName value is incorrect. You will have to another site name or a subdomain name

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
      ServerName site2.mysite.com
      ServerAdmin www@localhost
      DocumentRoot "/home/server/public_html/site2/"
      <Directory "/home/server/public_html/site2/">
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from All
               AllowOverride All
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

or

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
      ServerName www.site2.com
      ServerAdmin www@localhost
      DocumentRoot "/home/server/public_html/site2/"
      <Directory "/home/server/public_html/site2/">
               Order allow,deny
               Allow from All
               AllowOverride All
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```